# Exists Returning Too Many Rows

Tags: sql-server

If I use the line "where CS.cust_id in", I get a correct result (two items). However, If I substitute this with "where exists", I get every cust_id in the CS table which is obiously wrong. What am I doing wrong? (using SQLS 2008 R2).

```
select CS.cust_id, CS.cust_name_last
from bkorders.customers CS
-->where CS.cust_id in
-->where exists
(
  select OH.cust_id
  from bkorders.order_headers OH
  where (year(OH.order_date) = year(getdate())-1 and month(OH.order_date) = 10)   
  and
  OH.cust_id in
  (
    select OH.cust_id
    from bkorders.order_headers OH
    where (year(OH.order_date) = year(getdate())-1 and month(OH.order_date) = 11)
  )
    and
    OH.cust_id in
    (
      select OH.cust_id
      from bkorders.order_headers OH
      where (year(OH.order_date) = year(getdate())-1 and month(OH.order_date) = 12)
    )
)
```

;
go

Answer (score 1):

Correlate the exists subquery:

```
select CS.cust_id, CS.cust_name_last
from bkorders.customers CS
where exists
(
  select OH.cust_id
  from bkorders.order_headers OH
  where (year(OH.order_date) = year(getdate())-1 and month(OH.order_date) = 10)  
  and  CS.cust_id = OH.cust_id --> this
  and
  OH.cust_id in
  (
    select OH.cust_id
    from bkorders.order_headers OH
    where (year(OH.order_date) = year(getdate())-1 and month(OH.order_date) = 11)
  )
    and
    OH.cust_id in
    (
      select OH.cust_id
      from bkorders.order_headers OH
      where (year(OH.order_date) = year(getdate())-1 and month(OH.order_date) = 12)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you want to use `WHERE EXISTS` instead of `WHERE ... IN` ?

Remember that `WHERE EXISTS` will return any records as long as the subquery after EXISTS returns at least one record, since there is no correlation between your subquery and your main query (which explains why you get all the records from bkorders.customers in this case). On the other hand, `WHERE CS.cust_id IN` limits your results to only those customers whose cust_id are among those returned from the subquery.

Comment: Hi Dan: I understand the where...in syntax but I need to learn correlated subq's, that's why I went that route. Thanks for your input; now I understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

**where CS.cust_id in** has a filter condition for CS.cust_id
and **where exists** not have any filter condition..